# What hiking or other outdoor options can I do in Sanya in December?

Tags: china, hiking, outdoor-activities

I will be at a conference at the [Tsinghua Sanya International Mathematics Forum](http://www.tsimf.cn/en/index) December 17–21.  I don't know the weather well, but I've been keeping an eye on the forecast, and it looks like it's lovely right now, so hopefully it won't be too cold in December.  My previous trip to China (well, Hong Kong) spoiled me with all the excellent hiking.  I don't expect nearly the same level of hikeability on an island, but maybe there's something.

Is there any hiking or other outdoor activity that can be done:

1. alone,
2. without much equipment, and
3. hopefully without needing a car in the area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say go scuba diving. You won't need equipment, as you can rent all the equipment you need. Hainan is very warm all the year, and in the 20s during the winter, so temperature is not an issue. Otherwise, you can just enjoy some time on the beaches.

Be careful of the local "seafood restaurants", though. They are well known to scam customers, and I'm sure they will attempt to extort even more out of you if you don't speak Chinese. Avoid those, and don't visit any dining establishemeny your taxi driver recommend to you. Only visit well established restaurants.

Comment: It looks like this picked up a downvote somehow, but, for what it's worth, it wasn't me.  (I upvoted.)  I'll wait a bit to see if anyone has other suggestions, but otherwise will accept in a while.  Thanks!

Comment: @LSpice I suppose you can go surfing too, but I'm less sure about that. Scuba diving is quite common OTOH.