# Are there tourist traps in the Sanya tourist area?

Tags: china, tourist-traps

I am at a conference at [TSIMF](http://www.tsimf.cn/index), and the featured outing is an excursion to "the tourist area" tomorrow afternoon.  I thought this was just informal terminology, but the (sparse) program materials refer to paying an entrance fee, and TSIMF's [Sanya tour](http://www.tsimf.cn/en/news/page?id=394&nav=6) page features a picture of the Nanshan Cultural Tourism Zone, which I guess is what is meant.

When I hear "tourist area", I think of a place that I want to avoid, far from paying to enter, where mainly it'll be a game of avoiding the people who want to sell me things.
I am much more interested in seeing the nature on the island (as in [my other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126281/what-hiking-or-other-outdoor-options-can-i-do-in-sanya-in-december)).  However, the picture and brief description on the [TSIMF page](http://www.tsimf.cn/en/news/page?id=394&nav=6) actually looks kind of appealing, even within these constraints.  I'd like to hear people's experience of the sights in this area, and if it has appeal beyond shopping.

Comment: nobody here can answer if something is worth it. But you might get some facts from those who have been there.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attraction_Review-g297427-d600427-Reviews-Nanshan_Cultural_Tourist_Area-Sanya_Hainan.html will be helpful also.

Comment: Sanya is not known for its old and amazing culture but there are some nice to see there depending what you interests are

Answer (score 1):

Well, from [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sanya):

> 1 DaDongHai (BigEastSea) (大东海; Dadonghai) (From the airport, take bus
>   nr. 8.). The main "foreigner area" (especially Russian -- in visitors
>   and signage, there is little English here!) Dadonghai is an easily
>   accessible, beautiful beach -- and tourist/laowai haven. It has a good
>   balance between development and natural beauty. The water is decently
>   clean; the ocean bed is mostly just sand with a rare school of fish or
>   eel. The beach is lined with expensive (and generally not very tasty)
>   restaurants, but the beach is free (although cordoned into "zones" for
>   swimming and boating). The beach is closed at night, but there is a
>   section to the far east (the "military zone") that is just beyond a
>   big fence (with a big hole in it) which is always open. It is not
>   policed or seemingly controlled. The town behind Dadong Bay is more
>   expensive than Sanya, but has foreign restaurants. The shopping,
>   however, may not be as good as Sanya city's. See the beach both in the
>   morning, at sunset (sets gorgeously over the hills), and at night
>   (when people are more scarce). There're beach parties here on
>   weekends, especially, starting early but picking up later (usually
>   after hours) at the "Beach Bar", located in the middle of the
>   beachhead. Just look for music, foreigners, fire torches, and dancing
>   after midnight

Key to note that there's a 'good balance between development and natural beauty'. So hopefully from this, it won't be a total tourist trap for you, although that's obviously a bit subjective.

Comment: It's hard to guess from that writeup though which part would require an entry fee. In fact it seems like more of a puzzle now. The fee could be for [Yalong Bay](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowUserReviews-g297427-d568534-r166478335-Yalong_Bay-Sanya_Hainan.html), which seems to be the beach area. But that conflicts with your writeup where it specifically says "free"...